# Moto how to create EC2 instance - InvalidAMIID.NotFound

Tags: amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-ec2, boto3, moto

Using [moto](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/) how can you create an EC2 instance since theres no AMIs available to launch an instance with.
This repo seems to be "pre-loading" AMIs that are later used within tests but im not sure how these are being created
https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/tests/test_ec2/test_instances.py#L25
https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/moto/ec2/resources/amis.json

I've tried calling `.describe_images(Owners=["amazon"])` however, all the AMIs returned when used in the run_instances call give the below error.

```
from moto import mock_ec2


@mock_ec2
def Test_create_ec2():
    boto3.client('ec2').run_instances(ImageId="ami-1234abcd", MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)

botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAMIID.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances operation: The image id '[ami-1234abcd]' does not exist
```

This issue also relates to the unresolved question [How to create ami with specific image-id using moto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53716949/how-to-create-ami-with-specific-image-id-using-moto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `describe_images` does give a list of all available ImageId's.
The following test works against the current development branch of Moto:

```
@mock_ec2
def test_all_images():
    client = boto3.client("ec2", region_name="us-east-1")
    images = client.describe_images(Owners=["amazon"])["Images"]
    for image in images:
        client.run_instances(ImageId=image["ImageId"], MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
```

---

The preloaded images come from this file:
https://github.com/spulec/moto/blob/master/moto/ec2/resources/amis.json

If you want to substitute your own AMI's, you can use the following environment variable:
`MOTO_AMIS_PATH=/full/path/to/amis.json`

This JSON-file has to be in the same format as the one linked above.
Note that the environment variable has to be set before Moto is initialized - these AMI's are loaded the moment you call `from moto import mock_ec2`, so the environment variable has to be set before that import takes place.